# Unable to login into Sabre red workspace in sandbox mode

Tags: sabre

I am not able to login to Sabre workspace in sandbox mode. I have followed the guide and am using 2.12 version. I am using the -Dredapp.fake.session=true option and Validate Plugins does not report any errors. I am not using VPN.

```
Nov 22, 2015 7:01:55 AM com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.ui.dialogs.SignInDialog okPressed
INFO: SignInDialog okPressed time 22 Nov 2015, 07:01:55:674 AM
Nov 22, 2015 7:01:55 AM com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.prefs.PropertiesFileStorage <init>
INFO: C:\Sabre\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\RedAppRun/config.ini
Nov 22, 2015 7:01:55 AM com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService readProxySettings
INFO: Retrieving proxy data from: C:\Sabre\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\RedAppRun\config.ini
Nov 22, 2015 7:01:55 AM com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.ProfileService signIn
INFO: Performing sign in
Nov 22, 2015 7:01:56 AM com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService getResponseCode
SEVERE: Unable to read response code from connection
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.getResponseCode(RestService.java:442)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:236)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:174)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:158)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.getAsString(RestService.java:384)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.connectors.URLConnectionConnector.authenticateProfile(URLConnectionConnector.java:123)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.connectors.URLConnectionConnector.signIn(URLConnectionConnector.java:408)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.ProfileService.signIn(ProfileService.java:212)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.ui.dialogs.SignInDialog$8.run(SignInDialog.java:1099)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:205)
    ... 8 more
Nov 22, 2015 7:01:56 AM com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.connectors.URLConnectionConnector handleAuthenticationException
SEVERE: Received general exception from REST service
com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.RestException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:220)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:174)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:158)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.getAsString(RestService.java:384)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.connectors.URLConnectionConnector.authenticateProfile(URLConnectionConnector.java:123)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.connectors.URLConnectionConnector.signIn(URLConnectionConnector.java:408)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.internal.ProfileService.signIn(ProfileService.java:212)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.sso.ui.dialogs.SignInDialog$8.run(SignInDialog.java:1099)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sabre.edge.platform.core.rest.services.RestService.execute(RestService.java:205)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Eclipse version are you using? Why not use the most up to date SDK (SDK 2.13.2)?